Can I replace gmail.readonly with SMTP/IMAP details?
We are developing a Google workplace addon that requires the following API scope :

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send

I also need access to the .readonly scope, but it's restricted, and getting an audit from a third party is not something that we are looking to get into.
So, is it possible to get the basic functionality done with the gmail.send API and then, for premium plans ask the user for their IMAP/SMTP details? I also want the app to be listed on Google workspace's addon store.

To clarify, you're creating a Google Workspace add-on and want it to have https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send at first. Afterwards, if a user chooses to upgrade, so to speak, you want the add-on to also have https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly. Would that be correct?

@Saddles the gmail.readonly requires advanced verification. I need to pay big firms big money to audit the app. gmail.send does not require that level of verification.

The users can still give me read access to their inbox by sending me the SMTP details of their gmail account. I just want to make sure my plugin won't be delisted for finding a "way around" the gmail.readonly access
